# Get nearest ancestor by tag name in xslt

Tags: xslt, ancestor

I have xml file with following structure

```
<abc:element name="Super A">
    ...(some of other tags)
        <abc:element name="A">
           ...(some of other tags)
              <abc:element name="1A">
                    ...(some of other tags)
                        <abc:element name="ABC">
                            <abc:docs>
                                <abc:text> 
                                     Some text
                                </abc:text>
                            </abc:docs>
                        </abc:element>   
                    ...(some of other tags)
               </abc:element>
           ...(some of other tags)
        </abc:element>
    ...(some of other tags)
</abc:element>
```

And I'm in <`abc:element name="ABC">` node and I want to get only nearest ancestor with tag `<abc:element>`. In above example is `<abc:element name="1A">`. I try some of methods but none return expected results. Example I try use this:`<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::abc:element[1]"/>` but this return all of elements not only nearest. How to get expected by me result? It's possible in xslt?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show us minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, output you want and the one you get together with information about which software you use to run that? The path `ancestor::abc:element[1]` looks right at a first glance, not sure where things go wrong.

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced from your description: see: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/bFDb2BS/1 So you must be doing something different from what you describe.

Comment: The attributes "name" in my example is only added for simplify describe my problem. I only know that I am in `<abc:element>`  tag and i want go to nearest ancestor tag `<abc:element>`

Comment: The attribute `name` in MY example is used to show that the selection is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Try ancestor::node()[1]/abc:element

Comment: 1. That would return the context node. 2. Let's see what the actual problem is, before suggesting solutions.